# How to make the background of a container totally transparent?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in Bootstrap and want to make a containers background completely transparent. The container by default has a white background and I just want to completely remove that. Here is what I tried:

```
/* didn't work */
div.container {
    background-color:transparent;
}

/* didn't work either */
div.container {
    background:none;
}
```

How to do that ? If you guys have some suggestions (e.g. use well/panels etc.) for me, please post that in answers below. Thanks.

Comment: try background-color:transparent !important; but maybe background under container is white.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Actually, the `body` element was defaulted to show white in its background. Setting body's `background-color:transparent` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!important` with the css rule.

```
div.container {
    background-color:transparent !important;
}
```